# wso2 api manager 4.1.0 and apictl

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I built wso2 api manager 4.1.0 with docker image. I need to api logs json format.
Then installed apictl from this url "https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/api-controller/getting-started-with-wso2-api-controller/" and deployed to docker wso2 api manager container.
I could add environment and successfully login. Then i could see and change api log type as below.

.`/apictl get api-logging -e development`

```
API_ID                                 API_CONTEXT                 LOG_LEVEL
77bcdc16-8091-4785-....-...           /Service1/v1                   FULL
8eb0b33e-98c3-4a9d-....-....          /Service2.asmx/1.0             OFF
```

But there's not any log record in api.log. How can i see api json logs ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to send an API request to the API. Then only it logs those requests

Comment: Of course i called service then :)

Comment: I tried this in APIM 4.1.0 and I could see the logs.

Comment: Which path did you create for apictl ? How did you add enviroment ? with localhost or ip.
And did you use wso2 docker image ? I guess i missing something but i could'nt find any error log about it

Comment: I used localhost and used the zip of APIM 410.

Comment: I used localhost too. Maybe it could be about wso2 api manager docker image. Because i can change api log type without error but there's no any record in api.log